# Jetpack Compose DatePicker is taking empty space even if title and headline are empty

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-datepicker

Compose DatePicker is taking empty space even if the title and headline are empty.

It's already published as a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/267194809

**DatePicker:**

```
DatePicker(
    state = rememberDatePickerState(),
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    title = {
        // empty
    },
    headline = {
        // empty
    }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hope this solution will remove the empty space.*

1. Just type **'null'** in the **title** and **headline**;
2. Then, you need to put **'false'** in the **showModeToggle** parameter.

Here is the solution:

```
DatePicker(
    state = rememberDatePickerState(),
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    title = null,
    headline = null,
    showModeToggle = false
)
```